# Grunt git "typechange: node_modules/.bin/grunt" error

Tags: git, bash, powershell, gruntjs

I work on a project and used grunt but my problem is when I try to create a git add .

I get an error below is the log. Hope someone can please help me btw I use PowerShell in vs code on Windows 10. I tested it also with other terminals like git bash still the same error message.

Looking forward to some ideas how we could fix it, please.

```
> PS C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\Dropbox\testing-site1> git add . 
> error: open("node_modules/.bin/grunt"): Invalid argument error: unable to index file node_modules/.bin/grunt fatal: updating files failed


> PS C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\Dropbox\testing-site1> git status 
> On branch master Changes not staged for commit:
> typechange: node_modules/.bin/grunt
```

I also got a .gitignore file in the directory with following code to exclude the node modules from git but I still get this issue explained above.

```
node_modules/
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.gitignore` doesn't seem to be working.

I'm guessing that your `.gitignore` was added after some commit(s).

In which case you could try:

1. Removing the paths to your files from the git index recursively.
2. Then adding them back.

You can do this by running the following commands:

```bash
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Make .gitignore work successfully"
```

***Note:** You may want to try the above on a duplicate of your project directory as a test first.*

Comment: Thanks so much again appreciate it :)